# how to share user specific data without making use of sessions in .net

Tags: c#, .net, cookies, asp.net-mvc-4, session-state

Here I came across a situation where I need to share the user specific data between pages (like firstname/lastname/email etc.) without making use of session.

The reason why I can't make use of session is because we are using load balancer, which may allot different machine to serve the user's request.

So my company had strictly stated to avoid making use of sessions.

We cannot use datastore (sql) to store sessions, because of some restriction again.

Now, a critical question here is that how can we share the user specific data without making use of sessions/cookies/datastores.

I am left with one option to ping database on each request to fetch user specific information (which is obviously not an recommended approach)

Can anyone help me to suggest what can be done to share the user specific information across the pages.

Note: I am using MVC4 (Razor engine)

Answer (score 1):

> I am left with one option to ping database on each request to fetch
>   user specific information (which is obviously not an recommended
>   approach)

As a matter of fact that's the recommended approach. And if you are afraid that you might generate lots of traffic to your database you could always cache the results. Be careful to use a user specific key for the cache to avoid mixing information between the users. Also you might consider using a distributes cache such as `memcached` across your nodes.

Comment: cache cannot be used to share userspecific information. can you give an example which can clarify how I can make use of cache to share user specific data?

Comment: Of course that it can be used, just like that: `MemoryCache.Default["profile_" + User.Identity.Name] = userSpecificInformation;`. As I explained in my answer you need to use a user specific key for your cache. That's all.

Comment: + 1 to the use of memcached like store that enables fast lookup.

Comment: @Darin, thats look good, but what if loadbalancer alloted different machine to serve the request...is that cached object will be available to other server also? if yes then how? we are not using dedicated server for caching

Comment: @anilpurswani, if you use in memory cache then of course that it won't be available. That's why I suggested you in my answer to use a distributed cache for this scenario. One example is `memcached`.

Answer (score 0):

Cookies can be used.

- It will consume addition load while transferring between browser and server.
- It will be stored in Client machine.
- You can encrypt/decrypt data for security with custom code.